# How to read the variables in a HTML using xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-crawler

For example, the HTML page is like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var a = ["1", "2", "3"]
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can I get the "1", "2", "3"?

Comment: `xpath` works with HTML tags, not with JavaScript code. You can get javascript only as one string and you have to use standard string functions or regex.

Comment: BTW if you get string `["1", "2", "3"]` then you have correct JSON string and you can use `json` module to convert to python list.